# Ad window popping up on Windows 10. Am I infected?

Tags: malware, virus, chrome, windows-10

I was working with my PC (Windows 10 Fall Creators Update version 1709, build 16299.64) and this ad appeared in the corner:

[image: Screenshot of ad.]

I've never seen such a window before. I suspected it came from Telegram, closed it, but the ad still remained. It wasn't from the notifications center either. I clicked on it, and the page `https://www.filimo.com/m/KJM7w` opened in Chrome, even though my default browser is Edge.

So is this a new way of advertising in Windows 10, or am I infected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a chrome notification. No local malware. You must have accidentally allowed notifications in chrome for `aparat.com`.

Try [following these steps to disable notifications](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Alternatively, click on the cog wheel at the top right when this appears again.

Generally, websites can use the [notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) to send notifications to your device. This website just happened to send an ad for a change.

Note that if you don't remember explicitly allowing these notifications ever or have never even heard of this site, there is a chance that some local malware has enabled these notifications without your knowledge.